# Looping through Get Request in Python

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, get-request

I am trying to scrape some ticketing inventory info using Stubhub's API, but I cannot seem to figure out how to loop through the get request.

I basically want to loop through multiple events. The eventid_list is a list of eventids. The code I have is below:

```
inventory_url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v2'

for eventid in eventid_list:
    data = {'eventid': eventid, 'rows':500}
    inventory = requests.get(inventory_url, headers=headers, params=data)
    inv = inventory.json()
    print(inv)

listing_df = pd.DataFrame(inv['listing'])
```

When I run this, the dataframe only returns results for one event, instead of multiple. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: print(inv) outputs something like this:

```
{
    'eventId': 102994860, 
    'totalListings': 82, 
    'totalTickets': 236, 
    'minQuantity': 1, 
    'maxQuantity': 6, 
    'listing': [
        {
            'listingId': 1297697413, 
            'currentPrice': {'amount': 108.58, 'currency': 'USD'}, 
            'listingPrice': {'amount': 88.4, 'currency': 'USD'}, 
            'sectionId': 1638686, 
            'row': 'E', 
            'quantity': 6, 
            'sellerSectionName': 'FRONT MEZZANINE RIGHT', 
            'sectionName': 'Front Mezzanine Sides', 
            'seatNumbers': '2,4,6,8,10,12', 
            'zoneId': 240236, 
            'zoneName': 'Front Mezzanine', 
            'deliveryTypeList': [5], 
            'deliveryMethodList': [23, 24, 25], 
            'isGA': 0, 
            'dirtyTicketInd': False, 
            'splitOption': '2', 
            'ticketSplit': '1', 
            'splitVector': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 
            'sellerOwnInd': 0, 
            'score': 0.0
        }, 
        ...
        {
            'listingId': 1297697417, 
            'currentPrice': {'amount': 108.58, 'currency': 'USD'}, 
            'listingPrice': {'amount': 88.4, 'currency': 'USD'}, 
            'sectionId': 1638686, 
            'row': 'D', 
            'quantity': 3, 
            'sellerSectionName': 'FRONT MEZZANINE RIGHT', 
            'sectionName': 'Front Mezzanine Sides', 
            'seatNumbers': '2,4,6', 
            'zoneId': 240236, 
            'zoneName': 'Front Mezzanine', 
            'deliveryTypeList': [5], 
            'deliveryMethodList': [23, 24, 25], 
            'isGA': 0, 
            'dirtyTicketInd': False, 
            'splitOption': '2', 
            'ticketSplit': '1', 
            'splitVector': [1, 3], 
            'sellerOwnInd': 0, 
            'score': 0.0
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: `listing_df = pd.DataFrame(inv['listing'])` is outside of the `for` loop. All iterations of `for eventid in eventid_list:` complete (and get thrown away), and then when it finishes, you collect the very last result. You need some container _inside_ the `for` loop to collect every result of `inv = inventory.json()`. Simply indenting `listing_df = pd.DataFrame(inv['listing'])` won't fix it though.

Comment: Can you print `inv` and update your question with it?

Comment: @PauloScardine I've just updated my question!

Comment: @roganjosh how would I do that?

Comment: To re-interpret the suggestion of @PauloScardine, they were asking for some kind of representative output. Is it a dictionary/list/other? I said "some container", maybe you could just append all your results to a list within the `for` loop, but we don't really know what you're working with.

Comment: @roganjosh the inv output is a dictionary.

Comment: Domo arigato, Yukino, we just wanted to see an example of that output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `inventory.json()['listing']` is a list of events. If so, you can try this:

```
inventory_url = 'https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v2'

def get_event(eventid):
    """Given an event id returns inventory['listing']"""
    data = {'eventid': eventid, 'rows':500}
    inventory = requests.get(inventory_url, headers=headers, params=data)
    return inventory.json().get('listing', [])

# Concatenate output of all events
events = itertools.flatten(get_event(eventid) for eventid in eventid_list)

listing_df = pd.DataFrame(list(events))
```

This is just a starting point, you will have to deal with cases where `inventory.statos_code != 200`. The result probably is not very useful, so you may have to flat some of the attributes for the listing items line `currentPrice` and `listingPrice`:

[image]

Comment: It's a dictionary apparently, which complicates things in terms of the final DataFrame :(

Comment: Looks like it is a list of dicts.

Comment: it seems so, but the translation of that to a meaningful DF is not always straightforward.

Comment: Indeed, OP may have to return a coherent structure from get_event.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thank you so much for this. This is a great starting point. I keep getting this, though. `AttributeError: module 'itertools' has no attribute 'flatten'`. Can I use the attribute 'chain' instead?

Comment: Sorry, I probably got it mixed up something from clojure, in Python it is `itertools.chain` indeed.